# “stop” command changed the window style

Tags: command-line

What does `stop` command do in Ubuntu?

Details: I was installing some plugins from the terminal and I got an error. The last phrase was something like " Could not find directory. Stop. " I was just going with the flow and typed `stop` in the terminal. Just that: `stop`. I got a message telling me " stopped/killed process -some numbers-". I know I have done something stupid because when I try to run my programs( from the IDE) I get an ugly looking window. It works but it wasn’t like that before. 
This is what i mean by ugly:
[image]

The windows on Ubuntu are still the same. It seems that the change was applied only to the windows created by the programs written by me.

Is there a way to reverse it?

Comment: I discovered the changes after closing the terminal so I don't know exactly the number of the process that got killed

Comment: Read `man stop`

Comment: Just executing `stop` should give an error about missing job name. What's the output of `type -a stop`?

Comment: the output of "type -a stop" is "stop is sbin/stop" . Just that

Comment: Did you try to reboot? I don't whether it's really worth digging for the process instead of just restart your machine…

Comment: I'll try restarting then

Comment: @dessert Okay, I just had to restart. Thank you !

Comment: @Zethel You're welcome. Just remember to be careful with the terminal, it really has superpowers.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Upstart or Unity. I can consistently make Unity die using just the `stop` command without any arguments, but for whatever reason, this only happens in the GUI terminal. I can set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and `UPSTART_SESSION` in an SSH session to restart Unity, but this bug doesn't happen there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to say what process you killed that is responsible for that behaviour, but a simple **reboot** will just start it normally again.